# How do I extract a sub-hash from a hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash:

```
h1 = {:a => :A, :b => :B, :c => :C, :d => :D}
```

What is the best way to extract a sub-hash like this?

```
h1.extract_subhash(:b, :d, :e, :f) # => {:b => :B, :d => :D}
h1 #=> {:a => :A, :c => :C}
```

Comment: side note: http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/slice%21

Comment: @JanDvorak This question is not only about returning subhash but also about modifying existing one.  Very similar things but ActiveSupport has different means to deal with them.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

If you specifically want the method to return the extracted elements but h1 to remain the same:

```
h1 = {:a => :A, :b => :B, :c => :C, :d => :D}
h2 = h1.select {|key, value| [:b, :d, :e, :f].include?(key) } # => {:b=>:B, :d=>:D} 
h1 = Hash[h1.to_a - h2.to_a] # => {:a=>:A, :c=>:C}
```

And if you want to patch that into the Hash class:

```
class Hash
  def extract_subhash(*extract)
    h2 = self.select{|key, value| extract.include?(key) }
    self.delete_if {|key, value| extract.include?(key) }
    h2
  end
end
```

If you just want to remove the specified elements from the hash, that is much easier using [delete_if](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-delete_if).

```
h1 = {:a => :A, :b => :B, :c => :C, :d => :D}
h1.delete_if {|key, value| [:b, :d, :e, :f].include?(key) } # => {:a=>:A, :c=>:C} 
h1  # => {:a=>:A, :c=>:C}
```

Comment: This is O(n2) - you'll have one loop on the select, another loop on the include that will be called h1.size times.

Comment: While this answer is decent for pure ruby, if you're using rails, the below answer (using built-in `slice` or `except`, depending on your needs) is much cleaner

Comment: .slice & .except are the right answer, see bellow

Answer (score 156):

`ActiveSupport`, at least since 2.3.8, provides four convenient methods: `#slice`, `#except` and their destructive counterparts: `#slice!` and `#except!`. They were mentioned in other answers, but to sum them in one place:

```
x = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}
# => {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3, :d=>4}

x.slice(:a, :b)
# => {:a=>1, :b=>2}

x
# => {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3, :d=>4}

x.except(:a, :b)
# => {:c=>3, :d=>4}

x
# => {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3, :d=>4}
```

Note the return values of the bang methods.  They will not only tailor existing hash but also return removed (not kept) entries.  The `Hash#except!` suits best the example given in the question:

```
x = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4}
# => {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3, :d=>4}

x.except!(:c, :d)
# => {:a=>1, :b=>2}

x
# => {:a=>1, :b=>2}
```

`ActiveSupport` does not require whole Rails, is pretty lightweight.  In fact, a lot of non-rails gems depend on it, so most probably you already have it in Gemfile.lock. No need to extend Hash class on your own.

Comment: The result of `x.except!(:c, :d)` (with bang) should be `# => {:a=>1, :b=>2}`. Good if you can edit your answer.

Answer (score 42):

[Ruby 2.5](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2017/12/25/ruby-2-5-0-released/) added [Hash#slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-slice):

```
h = { a: 100, b: 200, c: 300 }
h.slice(:a)           #=> {:a=>100}
h.slice(:b, :c, :d)   #=> {:b=>200, :c=>300}
```

Answer (score 30):

**If you use rails**, [Hash#slice](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/slice) is the way to go.

```
{:a => :A, :b => :B, :c => :C, :d => :D}.slice(:a, :c)
# =>  {:a => :A, :c => :C}
```

**If you don't use rails**, [Hash#values_at will return the values in the same order as you asked them](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-values_at) so you can do this:

```
def slice(hash, *keys)
  Hash[ [keys, hash.values_at(*keys)].transpose]
end

def except(hash, *keys)
  desired_keys = hash.keys - keys
  Hash[ [desired_keys, hash.values_at(*desired_keys)].transpose]
end
```

ex:

```
slice({foo: 'bar', 'bar' => 'foo', 2 => 'two'}, 'bar', 2) 
# => {'bar' => 'foo', 2 => 'two'}

except({foo: 'bar', 'bar' => 'foo', 2 => 'two'}, 'bar', 2) 
# => {:foo => 'bar'}
```

**Explanation:**

Out of `{:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3}` we want `{:a => 1, :b => 2}`

```
hash = {:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3}
keys = [:a, :b]
values = hash.values_at(*keys) #=> [1, 2]
transposed_matrix =[keys, values].transpose #=> [[:a, 1], [:b, 2]]
Hash[transposed_matrix] #=> {:a => 1, :b => 2}
```

If you feels like monkey patching is the way to go, following is what you want:

```
module MyExtension
  module Hash 
    def slice(*keys)
      ::Hash[[keys, self.values_at(*keys)].transpose]
    end
    def except(*keys)
      desired_keys = self.keys - keys
      ::Hash[[desired_keys, self.values_at(*desired_keys)].transpose]
    end
  end
end
Hash.include MyExtension::Hash
```

Comment: Mokey patching is definitely the way to go IMO. Much cleaner and makes the intent clearer.

Comment: Add to modify code to address corectly core module, define module and import extend Hash core...      
 module CoreExtensions  
  module Hash  
    def slice(*keys)  
      ::Hash[[keys, self.values_at(*keys)].transpose]  
    end  
  end
end

Hash.include CoreExtensions::Hash

Answer (score 6):

You can use slice!(*keys) which is available in the core extensions of ActiveSupport

```
initial_hash = {:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3, :d => 4}

extracted_slice = initial_hash.slice!(:a, :c)
```

initial_hash would now be

```
{:b => 2, :d =>4}
```

extracted_slide would now be

```
{:a => 1, :c =>3}
```

You can look at `slice.rb in ActiveSupport 3.1.3`

Comment: I think you are describing extract!.  extract! removes the keys from the initial hash, returning a new hash containing the removed keys.  slice! does the opposite: remove all *but* the specified keys from the initial hash (again, returning a new hash containing the removed keys).  So slice! is a bit more like a "retain" operation.

Comment: ActiveSupport is not part of the Ruby STI

Answer (score 5):

```
module HashExtensions
  def subhash(*keys)
    keys = keys.select { |k| key?(k) }
    Hash[keys.zip(values_at(*keys))]
  end
end

Hash.send(:include, HashExtensions)

{:a => :A, :b => :B, :c => :C, :d => :D}.subhash(:a) # => {:a => :A}
```

Comment: Nice job.  Not quite what he's asking for. Your method returns: {:d=>:D, :b=>:B, :e=>nil, :f=>nil}
{:c=>:C, :a=>:A, :d=>:D, :b=>:B}

Comment: An equivalent one-line (and perhaps faster) solution:<pre>  `def subhash(*keys) 
    select {|k,v| keys.include?(k)}
  end`

Answer (score 4):

```
h1 = {:a => :A, :b => :B, :c => :C, :d => :D}
keys = [:b, :d, :e, :f]

h2 = (h1.keys & keys).each_with_object({}) { |k,h| h.update(k=>h1.delete(k)) }
  #=> {:b => :B, :d => :D}
h1
  #=> {:a => :A, :c => :C}
```

Answer (score 3):

Both `delete_if` and `keep_if` are part of Ruby core. Here you can achieve what you would like to without patching the `Hash` type.

```rb
h1 = {:a => :A, :b => :B, :c => :C, :d => :D}
h2 = h1.clone
p h1.keep_if { |key| [:b, :d, :e, :f].include?(key) } # => {:b => :B, :d => :D}
p h2.delete_if { |key, value| [:b, :d, :e, :f].include?(key) } #=> {:a => :A, :c => :C}
```

For futher info, check the links below from the documentation:

- [delete_if](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-delete_if)
- [keep_if](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-keep_if)

Answer (score 3):

if you want to extract from data base record also it is better to use `slice`

```
hash = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }
hash.slice!(:a, :b)  # => {:c=>3, :d=>4}
hash                 # => {:a=>1, :b=>2}
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-slice-21

Answer (score 2):

if you use rails, it may be convenient to use Hash.except

```
h = {a:1, b:2}
h1 = h.except(:a) # {b:2}
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, Ruby 2.5 added the Hash#slice method.

Rails 5.2.0beta1 also added it's own version of Hash#slice to shim the functionality for users of the framework that are using an earlier version of Ruby.
https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/01ae39660243bc5f0a986e20f9c9bff312b1b5f8

If looking to implement your own for whatever reason, it's a nice one liner as well:

```
 def slice(*keys)
   keys.each_with_object(Hash.new) { |k, hash| hash[k] = self[k] if has_key?(k) }
 end unless method_defined?(:slice)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Hash
  def extract(*keys)
    key_index = Hash[keys.map{ |k| [k, true] }] # depends on the size of keys
    partition{ |k, v| key_index.has_key?(k) }.map{ |group| Hash[group] }  
  end
end

h1 = {:a => :A, :b => :B, :c => :C, :d => :D}
h2, h1 = h1.extract(:b, :d, :e, :f)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick performance comparison of the suggested methods, `#select` seems to be the fastest

```
k = 1_000_000
Benchmark.bmbm do |x|
  x.report('select') { k.times { {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}.select { |k, _v| [:a, :b].include?(k) } } }
  x.report('hash transpose') { k.times { Hash[ [[:a, :b], {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}.fetch_values(:a, :b)].transpose ] } }
  x.report('slice') { k.times { {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}.slice(:a, :b) } }
end

Rehearsal --------------------------------------------------
select           1.640000   0.010000   1.650000 (  1.651426)
hash transpose   1.720000   0.010000   1.730000 (  1.729950)
slice            1.740000   0.010000   1.750000 (  1.748204)
----------------------------------------- total: 5.130000sec

                     user     system      total        real
select           1.670000   0.010000   1.680000 (  1.683415)
hash transpose   1.680000   0.010000   1.690000 (  1.688110)
slice            1.800000   0.010000   1.810000 (  1.816215)
```

The refinement will look like this:

```
module CoreExtensions
  module Extractable
    refine Hash do
      def extract(*keys)
        select { |k, _v| keys.include?(k) }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And to use it:

```
using ::CoreExtensions::Extractable
{ a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }.extract(:a, :b)
```

Comment: Considering the fact that the benchmark was done for just the one data set and that the results were all quite close I question whether there is a statistical basis for your conclusion "#select seems to be the fastest". As an aside, I re-ran your benchmark (pure Ruby, in March, 2022) and `slice` was nearly three times as fast as the other two.

Answer (score 0):

This code injects the functionality you're asking for into the Hash class:

```
class Hash
    def extract_subhash! *keys
      to_keep = self.keys.to_a - keys
      to_delete = Hash[self.select{|k,v| !to_keep.include? k}]
      self.delete_if {|k,v| !to_keep.include? k}
      to_delete
    end
end
```

and produces the results you provided:

```
h1 = {:a => :A, :b => :B, :c => :C, :d => :D}
p h1.extract_subhash!(:b, :d, :e, :f) # => {b => :B, :d => :D}
p h1 #=> {:a => :A, :c => :C}
```

Note: this method actually returns the extracted keys/values.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a functional solution that can be useful if you're not running on Ruby 2.5 and in the case that you don't wan't to pollute your Hash class by adding a new method:

```
slice_hash = -> keys, hash { hash.select { |k, _v| keys.include?(k) } }.curry
```

Then you can apply it even on nested hashes:

```
my_hash = [{name: "Joe", age: 34}, {name: "Amy", age: 55}]
my_hash.map(&slice_hash.([:name]))
# => [{:name=>"Joe"}, {:name=>"Amy"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition to slice method, if the subhash keys which you want to separate from original hash is going to be dynamic you can do like,

```
slice(*dynamic_keys) # dynamic_keys should be an array type
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do it by looping on keys only we want to extract and just checking the key is exist and then extract it.

```
class Hash
  def extract(*keys)
    extracted_hash = {}
    keys.each{|key| extracted_hash[key] = self.delete(key) if self.has_key?(key)}
    extracted_hash
  end
end
h1 = {:a => :A, :b => :B, :c => :C, :d => :D}
h2 = h1.extract(:b, :d, :e, :f)
```