# Ruby how to get partial hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I have a hash in ruby like this,

first = {:a=>1,:b=>2,:c=>3,:d=>4,:e=>5}

How can I achieve this by single line script

second = {:a=>1,:c=>3,:e=>5}

Thank you very much.

Comment: It has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025277/how-do-i-extract-a-sub-hash-from-a-hash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly what you want in a single pretty line of code

```
second = first.slice(:a, :c, :e) # => {:a=>1, :c=>3, :e=>5}
```

EDIT: previous answer was using Rails. This is a solution just using Ruby

```
second = first.delete_if {|k,v| ![:a, :c, :e].include?(k) } # => {:a=>1, :c=>3, :e=>5}
```

Comment: Can you confirm if this works with Hash? I get this error with Ruby 2.1 `NoMethodError: undefined method `slice' for {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3, :d=>4, :e=>5}:Hash`

Comment: slice is not a Hash method in core RUBY

Comment: I can use slice. What's the difference?

Comment: The difference is that slice is a Hash method provided in Rails while the other is in pure Ruby - Ruby Hash does not have the slice method. So if you are in Rails you can use slice as a convenient short code. Please, remember to tick as accepted one of the answers if any of them help you.

Answer (score 3):

Try `delete_if` or `keep_if`, both of them are part of core Ruby. Both of them operate on the current hash. `slice` is also part of core Ruby already.

```ruby
first =  {:a=>1,:b=>2,:c=>3,:d=>4,:e=>5}
first_clone = first.clone
p first.keep_if { |key| [:a, :c, :e].include?(key) } # =>  {:a=>1,:c=>3,:e=>5}
p first_clone.delete_if { |key, value| [:b, :d, :f].include?(key) } # =>  {:a=>1,:c=>3,:e=>5}
```

Documentation:

- [delete_if](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-delete_if)
- [keep_if](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-keep_if)
- [slice](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/Hash.html#method-i-slice)

Answer (score 2):

first.keep_if{|key| [:a,:c,:d].include?(key)}

Answer (score 0):

Method 1

```
first = {:a=>1,:b=>2,:c=>3,:d=>4,:e=>5}
first.delete(:b)
first.delete(:d)
second = first
```

Method 2

```
first = {:a=>1,:b=>2,:c=>3,:d=>4,:e=>5}
second = first.delete_if {|key, value| key == :b || key == :d }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't know the keys you want to keep / remove ... you could do it like this:

```
first = {:a=>1,:b=>2,:c=>3,:d=>4,:e=>5}
iterator = 0
second = {}
first.each_pair do |key, value|
  second[key] = value if iterator % 2 == 0
  iterator += 1
end

second # is now {:a=>1,:c=>3,:e=>5}
```

Comment: I take this only as an example and no index sequence associated

Comment: This code will select every other member of the hash, starting with the first. If you wanted the even members rather than the odd, then set the iterator modulus to 1 instead - `iterator % 2 == 1`.

Comment: Sorry, maybe it's my bad. I am not asking to get odd or even. I am asking to fetch any elements in the hash without specified pattern. Thank you anyway.