# Sequel adds single quotes to .where

Tags: ruby, postgresql, sequel

I'm using Sequel with a Sinatra API and Postgres. I have a basic dataset called 'results':

```
results = Receipt.order(Sequel.desc(:date))
```

I'm trying to filter it with a hash that comes in from a JSON object like this:

```
filters = {item: 'mortgage',
           method: 'check'}

def get_filtered_results(results, filters)
    filters.each do |key, value|
        results = results.where('? = ?', key, value)
    end
    return results
end
```

The sql query that's being generated by these '.where's is:

```
SELECT * FROM "receipts" WHERE ('item' = 'mortgage') and ('method' = 'check') ORDER BY "date" DESC LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0;
```

The quotes around 'item' and 'method' are causing the query not to return any results - when I run them manually without the quotes they return the expected records. I tried passing the filter in as a hash rather than a prepared statement, same result. Is there any way to construct the query without the quotes?

Edit: When I construct the statement in pry - so

```
Receipt.order(Sequel.desc(:date)).where(:item => 'mortgage payment').where(:method => 'check')
```

I get the expected results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the values that will be replaced in the placeholders are treated as strings and not as field names. You will have to interpolate the hash `key` in the query. However this makes the query vulnerable to attacks, so it's a good idea you create an array of allowed filters:

```
filters = {item: 'mortgage',
           method: 'check'}

def get_filtered_results(results, filters)
  allowed_filters = [:item, :method]

  filters.slice(*allowed_filters).each do |key, value|
    results = results.where("#{key} = ?", value)
  end
  return results
end
```

The `slice()` method will create a new Hash containing only the keys that are in the `allowed_filters` array.

Comment: Thanks! Since this isn't rails I couldn't use the 'slice' method but I used this in combination with the pure-ruby version here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21816435/2203829

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't pay attention that `slice` was a Rails method, but glad you worked it out :)