# Select key value pairs from a hash whose keys belong to an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of keys:

```
keys = ["first_name", "last_name", "foo"]
```

and a hash:

```
hsh = {"first_name" => "tester", "zoo" => "loo", "foo" => "bar"}
```

I want to extract the key-value pairs whose keys are present in the array, to get:

```
res = {"first_name" => "tester", "foo" => "bar"}
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025277/how-do-i-extract-a-sub-hash-from-a-hash) answer

Comment: you could try slice like in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7430343/ruby-easiest-way-to-filter-hash-keys#25206082) answer.

Comment: @Зелёный I have tried the approach given by farhatmihalko and it works. Was looking for different or more ruby way to do this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
hsh.select{ |k, v| keys.include?(k) }
```

Answer (score 11):

```
hsh.slice *keys
# => {"first_name" => "tester", "foo" => "bar"}
```

Comment: [map + each_with_object](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/69db8dc468c16a961d0ee55384f97a1ccbe02da3/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/hash/slice.rb#L21)

Comment: This is the way the go with Ruby >= 2.5.0 (Rails had this core extension earlier), no need for `.select{}`, `.reject{}` or `.keep_if{}` anymore. See [release notes](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2017/12/25/ruby-2-5-0-released/)

Answer (score 2):

It feels more natural to call `keep_if` instead of `select`:

```
hsh.keep_if { |key| keys.include? key }
```

Also, `keep_if` removes the unwanted pairs from the hash.

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach:

```
hsh.select { |k,_| k.in?(keys) }
# => {"first_name" => "tester", "foo" => "bar"}
```

Note that although this is shorter than using `include?`, it depends on Rails being present.

Comment: Numbers of characters only counts at [Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reject`:

```
hsh.reject { |k| !keys.include? k } #=> {"first_name"=>"tester", "foo"=>"bar"}
```