# ruby regex to find nil or blank values for import csv?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, rake

```
row = {"joining_date"=>"18/07/2015", "name"=>" Joe Doe ", "company"=>" Google", "location"=>" New York ", "role"=>"developer", "email"=>"joe@doe.com", "mobile"=>"11-(640)123-45674", "address"=>"4 XYZ Road", "validity"=>"true"}
```

`row` is invalid only if any one of the fields(`joining_date, name, company, location, email, address`) is `nil` or not `present`.

```
def is_valid?
  valid = true
  if row[:name] == nil || row[:joining_date] == nil || row[:address] == nil || row[:email] == nil || row[:company] == nil || row[:location] == nil
    valid = false
  end
  valid 
end
```

Is there any way that I can simplify and refactor the above method in rails to find it more efficient using regex?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, but I wouldn't use a regex as it's in a hash.  As you're using rails you can use `present?` or `blank?`.

```
row.values.any?(&:blank?)
```

Would return true if any are blank

for your case

```
def is valid?
  row.values.all?(&:present?)
end
```

Comment: Thanks. But I dont want to check for all the keys. It's only specific values should not be blank.

Comment: @Vinay then you just slice to just those keys, `row.slice(:key_1, :key_2, :key_3).values.all?(&:present?)`

Comment: @lusketeer row.slice? Undefined method for 'slice' for HASH

Comment: @Vinay it's a rails method, but if you wanna just do the ruby way, refer to this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30551934/1301840) just simply use [`values_at`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/values_at)